# Association is not created, after using has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :microposts
end

class Mircopost < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120216035330) do

  create_table "mircoposts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

I run rake db:migrate, rails console and create a fake user=User.create(:name => "abc"). However, it yields "NameError: uninitialized constant User::Micropost" when I run user.microposts.empty?. So I don't quite get why those methods are generated automatically. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: microposts or mircoposts... one is mispelled

Answer (score 1):

```
has_many :microposts
class Mircopost < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Answer (score 1):

you want create_table "microposts"

not

create_table "mircoposts"

then

user.microposts

will exist

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this for a different reason. I had scaffolded with the name "MicroPost" so rails created  a model called micro_post.rb and the schema.rb file creates a table called "micro_posts". Instead of "has_many :microposts" I had to use "has_many :micro_posts" then in the console use "first_user.micro_posts". Rails (or Ruby, not sure which) auto-magically inserted the underscore because of the second capital letter.